# Is it possible to force all Azure AD B2C MFA to be phone calls and never SMS?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

If this can be done through configuration great.

I'd also accept customising the UI to hide the buttons that refer to SMS if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible in built-in policies (user flows) using a custom page UI which hides the SMS button.

It is possible in custom policies using metadata as follows.

The phone factor provider provides supports the following metadata:

- **setting.authenticationMode**: Possible values: `mixed`, `phone`, or `sms`. The `mixed` value indicates both the "call" and "text" options are presented. The `phone` value indicates only the "call" option is presented. The `sms` value indicates only the "text" option is presented.
- **setting.autodial**: Possible values: `true` or `false`. If `setting.authenticationMode` is set to `call` or `sms` and this is set to `true`, then the phone number is dialled or messaged automatically without any user interaction.

Example:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PhoneFactor-InputOrVerify">
      <DisplayName>PhoneFactor</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.PhoneFactorProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="setting.authenticationMode">phone</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.autodial">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      ...
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```